# 13.04 does not recognise installation CD

Tags: updates, cd

I burned downloaded ISO to a CD and installed Ubuntu 13.04 from this disc.

When updating software (broadcom WIFI) the system asks me to load the "Raring Ringtail CD" - which I do, however Ubuntu does not recognise the CD and the installation grinds to a halt.

Is there some way to make label/name the CD so that when Ubuntu searches for it - it recognises the CD?

Comment: Is it a CD or a DVD? Ubuntu 13.04 is too large to fit onto a 700MB CD.

Answer (score 1):

Facing the same problem with Kubuntu 13.04.

Uncheck the CDRom option on the Ubuntu software tab.

This seems to work for me!!